# Passing data to DataProvider from Excel sheet Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project that has been test multiple credential so i write a script to access the excel file and then check it one by one.
Below code is for check the login status by selenium web driver The problem is that when i am adding selenium web driver jar they were not added the testing library issue on it.

> Any other way to test multiple login with excel sheet?

Thanks in Advance.,

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    **import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;**here is some issue this lib is not added in selenium jar.


    import jxl.Sheet;
    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

    public class ReadExcelDataProvider {
        public WebDriver driver;
        public WebDriverWait wait;
        String appURL = "https://www.linkedin.com/";

        //Locators
        private By byEmail = By.id("session_key-login");
        private By byPassword = By.id("session_password-login");
        private By bySubmit = By.id("signin");
        private By byError = By.id("global-alert-queue");

        @BeforeClass
        public void testSetup() {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        }


        @Test(dataProvider="empLogin")
        public void VerifyInvalidLogin(String userName, String password) {
            driver.navigate().to(appURL);
            driver.findElement(byEmail).sendKeys(userName);
            driver.findElement(byPassword).sendKeys(password);
            //wait for element to be visible and perform click
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(bySubmit));
            driver.findElement(bySubmit).click();

            //Check for error message
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byError));
            String actualErrorDisplayed = driver.findElement(byError).getText();
            String requiredErrorMessage = "Please correct the marked field(s) below.";
            Assert.assertEquals(requiredErrorMessage, actualErrorDisplayed);

        }

        @DataProvider(name="empLogin")
        public Object[][] loginData() {
            Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("D:/sampledoc.xls","Sheet1");
            return arrayObject;
        }

        /**
         * @param File Name
         * @param Sheet Name
         * @return
         */
        public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName) {
            String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
            try {
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
                Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

                int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
                int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

                arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows-1][totalNoOfCols];

                for (int i= 1 ; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {

                    for (int j=0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
                        arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
                    }

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BiffException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arrayExcelData;
        }

        @Test
        public void tearDown() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which Jar you added?

Comment: selenium-java-3.5.2 this one

Comment: u can add jar from build path. can i send how to add?

Comment: yes i added on it build path then lib to add jar its fine but they not worked

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: Are u adding jars of testng and jxl?

Comment: testng and selenium are diffirent libs, add both of them

Comment: where i found testing lib any link please share V-Rob

Comment: @asim : http://testng.org/doc/download.html